# variable "name of package" in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I use template in my project.
In template at "Version Control Settings" i have set path to repository `svn+ssh://path/to/repository/trunk/Linux/packages/` and add VCS rule:
`+|-:VCSPath => %env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%/%env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%-1.0` (full path to my package svn+ssh://path/to/repository/trunk/Linux/packages/name-of-package/name-of-package-1.0)

I set name "name-of-package" when i have create new "build configuration" from template. Then run the build. But teamcity has return an error:

```
Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"svn+ssh://path/to/repository/trunk/Linux/packages/" 
{instance id=12153,  
parent internal id=1927,    
parent id=Seek_SvnSshPathToRepositoryTrunkLinuxPackages,  
description: "svn: svn+ssh://path/to/repository/trunk/Linux/packages/"}'  
Path is invalid: 'svn+ssh://path/to/repository/trunk/Linux/packages/VCSPath'@14300: none
```

I guess that `%env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%` != "name-of-package"

Please, tell me which of environment variables can i use?

thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find a decision.
In VCS rule a have added `name-of-package/name-of-package-1.0`

Where name-of-package - name of my package.

And it has worked.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens when `url` is incorrect. Have you tried browsing the `url` in a browser? Does it work there?